# How to describe error in numerical method - big O notation

Tags: numerical-methods

I am a bit confused on how big O notation works for numerical methods.

Specifically, what I need to know is if I have an error of $1.226(10^{-3})$ for my numerical method, would that be considered $O(10^{-3})$ error?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: The point about the big O notation is that it describes how your error changes when some parameter goes to infinity, 0, or whatever value makes sense in your context. For example, $exp(x)=1+x+O(x^2)$ because the "error" is of order $x^2$ when $x\rightarrow 0$. It doesn't say anything about the absolute value of the error. Thus, a constant error of 1.226e-3 is $O(1)$. I however guess that you want to say something else, or not use the big O notation for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fundamental misunderstanding.
$O$ is all about limiting behaviour, usually as some parameter tends to $0$ or $\infty$.
It is not at all about particular numbers.

So if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are functions of $x$, $f(x) = O(g(x))$ as $x \to 0+$ means that
there exist some positive constants $\delta$ and $M$ such that $|f(x)| \le M g(x)$ for all $x$ with $0 < x < \delta$.  Similarly, $f(x) = O(g(x))$ as $x \to \infty$ means that there exist some positive constants $K$ and $N$ such that $|f(x)| \le K g(x)$ for all $x > N$.

In numerical methods, a parameter $\to 0+$ might be a step size, a parameter $\to \infty$ might be a number of iterations.  In either case, it's not about a calculation with one particular step size or number of iterations, it's about what happens when the step size gets arbitrarily small or the number of iterations gets arbitrarily large.

So maybe with step size $h = 10^{-3}$ you get an error of $1.226 \times 10^{-3}$, and with step size $h = 10^{-4}$ you get $1.212 \times 10^{-4}$, and with $h = 10^{-5}$ you get $1.219 \times 10^{-5}$.  That might be taken as numerical evidence that
your error is $O(h)$.  But you don't really know unless you do a theoretical analysis that considers what happens for arbitrary $h$.

Comment: Oh I see. This makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much for the help. :)